# How to do superscript in WP XAML?

Tags: silverlight, xaml, windows-phone-8

Here is the usercontrol which is used in my WP8 app. It displays current time. The fontsize is specified by the screen which uses this control.  I want AM to be on top but with inline with the text.

Here is my XAML code for control. Also note that Typography.Variants is not supported in WP8

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding BindingHour}" FontWeight="Bold" Name="txtHour" 
             Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"
            FontSize="{Binding BindingHourFontSize}" />
<TextBlock Text=":" FontWeight="ExtraLight"  
             Grid.Row="0"  Grid.Column="1"
            FontSize="{Binding BindingColonFontSize}" />
<TextBlock Text="{Binding BindingMinute}" FontWeight="Thin"  
            Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2"  
            FontSize="{Binding BindingMinuteFontSize}"/>

<TextBlock Text="{Binding BindingAmPm}" FontWeight="SemiBold" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="3" />

<TextBlock Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontWeight="SemiBold"
           Text="{Binding BindingFreeText}" Grid.ColumnSpan="5"/>
```

**Here is how it looks on the screen where i use above control.**

[image]

**Here is how i want it to look but not able to do it in XAML**. Also, superscript and subscript is not supported in WP XAML. odd.

[image]

Comment: Why are all the bindings two-way? That doesn't make any sense.

Comment: I will change that. This is just a demo code.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it appears that you can do it the same way it is done via WPF, through the `Typography.Variants` attached property.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/system.windows.documents.typography.variants(v=vs.105).aspx

which allows you to specify superscript/subscript variants of the font.  However, that's not really what you want.  Your AM/PM appears vertically aligned within the grid control.  If it appears too high relative to neighboring characters, simply push it down via its Margin.

Here is an example of the layout

```
<Grid
   Width="auto"
   Height="100"
   HorizontalAlignment="Center"
   VerticalAlignment="Center">
   <Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <RowDefinition/>
      <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
   </Grid.RowDefinitions>
   <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <ColumnDefinition/>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
      <ColumnDefinition/>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
   </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
   <TextBlock
      Grid.Column="0"
      Grid.Row="0"
      FontSize="80"
      Text="09"/>
   <TextBlock
      Grid.Column="1"
      Grid.Row="0"
      VerticalAlignment="Center"
      FontSize="50"
      Text=":"/>
   <TextBlock
      Grid.Column="2"
      Grid.Row="0"
      FontSize="80"
      Text="11"/>
   <TextBlock
      Margin="0 20 0 0"
      Grid.Column="3"
      Grid.Row="0"
      FontSize="20"
      Text="AM"/>
</Grid>
```

And a snapshot of how it looks

[image]

To keep relative positions the same while stretching/compressing to fill existing space, use ViewBoxes.

If you create the following, and paste the grid into each of the following ViewBoxes

```
<Grid
  Width="auto"
  Height="auto"
  HorizontalAlignment="Center"
  VerticalAlignment="Center">
  <Grid.RowDefinitions>
     <RowDefinition Height="100"/>
     <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
  </Grid.RowDefinitions>
  <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
     <ColumnDefinition/>
     <ColumnDefinition/>
  </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
  <Viewbox Grid.ColumnSpan="2"></Viewbox>
  <Viewbox Grid.Row="1"></Viewbox>
  <Viewbox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"></Viewbox>
</Grid>
```

you get the following

[image]

Comment: Setting margin wont work here. It is because font size can be anything. I can set a fixed margin when font size is fixed.
This is a custom control and hence i can't set Margin in custom control.  1st image in my OP, shows what happens when you set any margin. Also, it wont work because, i am using it in a listbox. in that case top margin will be different for each item.

Comment: @Nexus: That comment doesn't make sense.  I can guarantee you that it will push the AM/PM off from the top of the grid, bringing it down closer to the location where you want it.  Guaranteed.  Now, if you're saying that it doesn't always work because the numbers in the font have different height, that's a different issue.  So "never works" is so wrong.  You may need to clarify what is going on, because this works (adding image demonstrating it in a moment)

Comment: @Will: (re your edit) you have `Grid.Row` and `Grid.Column` in your properties... that tells me you're positioning the blocks within a grid.  Is this not correct?

Comment: Will: Yes. I am putting everything in a grid. Any other approach ? Also sorry for quick editing my reply :)

Comment: @Nexus: Please view the edit.  This should work fine for you.  Try it out and update your question with a new snapshot if it still looks wonky.

Comment: @Nexus hmmm... If you want to use the same layout, but zoomed in or out depending on how much room the time display has, have you thought about using a [ViewBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/system.windows.controls.viewbox(v=vs.105).aspx)?  You would, for example, wrap my grid in a ViewBox, which would keep the relative size and position of everything consistent as it is zoomed or shrunk.  That would get over any issue  of margins needing adjustment as size changes.

Comment: Your code works fine when it is pasted as it is. However, try doing same in custom control and expose the font-size so that it can be set from screen which uses it. In that case, if font size is changed you also need to change margin. Hence result is same as image 1 shown in my OP. No luck with ViewBox :(

Comment: @Nexus maybe forget about binding the font size and just go with "size these to fill the available space"?  Other than that, you'll have to override Measure and Arrange in the user control's base class in order to position everything correctly relative to font.  This would NOT be fun.  At all.  I'd highly suggest avoiding this.